# Tooltip on column value in row?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is it possible to add a dojo tooltip (Extension Lib) to a viewColumn?
I have tried embedding it within the viewColumn, between two columns, after last viewColumn in viewPanel and all bound to viewColumn-ID without success.

In source I can see that the div-tag for tooltip is created and with values in "label" but when hovering it doesn't display.

Comment: When you connect the Tooltip control (from extension library) to view column it generates code like `<div id="..." dojoType="extlib.dijit.Tooltip" label="Tooltip" connectId="view:_id1:viewPanel1:viewColumn1"></div>`. Notice the `connectId` which points to `view:_id1:viewPanel1:viewColumn1`. But View control does not generate any element with ID `view:_id1:viewPanel1:viewColumn1`. Instead it generates IDs like `view:_id1:viewPanel1:0:viewColumn1:_internalViewText` for columns. Also do you want the tooltip for entire column or cell.

Comment: I want it for each entry. Imaging a entry as a link and hover over will present a tooltip with more info about the underlying document. I can do it creating the HTML in the actual view column but I'd like to move from that type of design...

Answer (score 1):

You might need to place your tooltip in desired column (inside `viewcolumn` tag)  and set the `for` property to `_internalViewText`.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a repeat control for this instead of a view control. It is slightly more work but gives you better flexibility.